# How to get data value from input field inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

This is my html.
I want to get values from input field and pass to the controller.

```html
<fieldset class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="field in newField">
   <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding:0 16px 0 0;">Variants
     <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="field.variantName" placeholder="Option name">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding:0 0 0 16px"><br>
     <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="field.variantValue" placeholder="value" >
   </div>
 </fieldset>
```

Here is my controller:-

```js
add(prod) {
      var id   = this.saveddataprod.length;
      var json = {  
                   "id"          : id,
                   "variantsName"     : prod.variantsName,
                   "variantsValue"    : prod.variantsValue
                 };
      this.saveddataprod.unshift(json);
  };
```

Comment: Which data value?

Comment: hey R.J thanks. I want to get value from input field "ng-model="field.variantName"" pass to my controller. can you help me out? thanks

Comment: Sorry, Can you please your question elaborate ?

Comment: how to get value from input field pass to controller

Comment: you need each value or all value which would you put input ?

Comment: I need each value

Comment: I think you have everything in `newField`.You should do businned stuff in controller and not from html to controller.Please elaborate your requirement

Comment: You can try `array`.

Comment: it is dynamic, if I click the add variant button, It'll add another variant fields. now, I have no idea how to get the values from those input fields pass to my controller.

Comment: @fyeah where you mensioned `newField` in your controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See its simple to pass your input value to controller.
Because angular supports two way data binding.
**For Ex.**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="registration()">
   <label> Name </lbel>
   <input ng-model="name" />
</form>
```

Here if you want to use input `name` in the controller then,

```
$scope.name = {};

$scope.registration = function() {
   console.log("You will get the name here ", $scope.name);
};
```

In your case,
Your controller should be like:-

```
.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
   $scope.newField = // add data which you want

});
```

Comment: in your answer, in the controller if the value i wish to assign is in an <input> field that is inside an ng-repeat, how can i access the <input> field of a particular index value ? i.e How can i specify it in the controller which iteration contains the <input> elements i need ?

Comment: you can use `ng-change` directive on input element or you can pass ng-model value to controller through any method as a parameter

Comment: could you provide an example for the ng-change directive please ? :)

Answer (score 0):

May you need like this

```
<fieldset class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="field in newField">
<div class="col-lg-6" style="padding:0 16px 0 0;">Variants
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="modelName[$index].variantName" placeholder="Option name">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6" style="padding:0 0 0 16px"><br>
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="modelName[$index].variantValue" placeholder="value" >
</div>
```

> And use modelName variable after form submit like $scope.modelName or this.modelName in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports two way data binding so view and model are synchronized by framework.

According to comments i think this code should help You.
https://jsfiddle.net/y3Lhf6zo/2/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="container">
  <h1>Variants</h1>
  <fieldset class="row" ng-repeat="field in allFields">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="field.variantName" placeholder="Option name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="field.variantValue" placeholder="value" >
      <br/>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input class="btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Add new row" ng-click="addNewRow()">
  <input class="btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Show all" ng-click="showObject(allFields)">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.allFields = [
                   {variantName    : "Name0",
                   variantValue    : "Value0"},
                   {variantName    : "Name1",
                   variantValue    : "Value1"}];

  $scope.addNewRow = function() {
      $scope.allFields.push({variantName     : null,
                             variantValue    : null});
  }
  $scope.showObject = function(object) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(object));
  }
}
```